# All notifications for specific user are being deleted from database, when only one should be removed

Tags: java, android, firebase

The problem that I am having is that I have written two different methods: 1 for adding a notification to the database, and 1 for removing that notification. You receive a notification is another user likes your post, comments on your post, likes your comment, etc. In those cases the user whose post it is will receive a notification letting them know that you have liked their comment, or their post, etc.

The issue is that the notifications are being saved to the database just fine, but when a user for example unlikes a post, not just that notification is deleted, but all of the notifications of that user. I am not sure why this is happening, I would just like that one notification with its specific `notificationId` to be removed from the database, not all of the notifications that user has received.

[image]

**PostAdapter**

```
holder.like.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (holder.like.getTag().equals("like")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid()).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                addNotification(post.getPublisher(), post.getPostid());
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid()).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                deleteNotification(post.getPublisher());
            }
        });

 private void addNotification(final String userid, final String postid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(userid);

        String notificationId = reference.push().getKey();

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("userid", mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        hashMap.put("comment", "liked your event");
        hashMap.put("postid", postid);
        hashMap.put("notificationId", notificationId);
        hashMap.put("ispost", true);

        if (notificationId != null)
            reference.child(notificationId).setValue(hashMap);
    }

    private void deleteNotification(String userid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(userid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Notification notification = snapshot.getValue(Notification.class);
                    if (notification != null) {
                        reference.child(notification.getNotificationId()).removeValue();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**Second method**

```
holder.like.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (holder.like.getTag().equals("like")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid()).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                addNotification(post.getPublisher(), post.getPostid());
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid()).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notifications").child(post.getPublisher()).child(mNotificationId).removeValue();
            }
        });

private void addNotification(final String userid, final String postid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(userid);

        mNotificationId = reference.push().getKey();

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("userid", mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        hashMap.put("comment", "liked your event");
        hashMap.put("postid", postid);
        hashMap.put("notificationId", mNotificationId);
        hashMap.put("ispost", true);

        reference.child(mNotificationId).setValue(hashMap);
    }
```

Comment: Hi man, .getReference("Notifications").child(userid) check this line.  I think, you list all the notifications. And you remove all the notifications.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir Should I change the addNotification(); method then so that it doesn't have the userId? Am I adding it to the database correctly, or is there a better way to go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (notification != null) {
     reference.child(notification.getNotificationId()).removeValue();
}
```

These lines should change. Because the notification id is never null and all notifications are deleted.

```
if (notification.getUserId().equals(mFirebaseUser.getUid())) {
     reference.child(notification.getNotificationId()).removeValue();
}
```

Or you can save the notification id using another way and delete the notificaition  without checking all the notifications.

**Add func:**

```
private void addNotification(final String userid, final String postid) 
{
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(userid);

mNotificationId = reference.push().getKey();

HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("userid", mFirebaseUser.getUid());
hashMap.put("comment", "liked your event");
hashMap.put("postid", postid);
hashMap.put("notificationId", mNotificationId);
hashMap.put("ispost", true);

reference.child(mNotificationId).setValue(hashMap);

HashMap<String, Object> hashMap2 = new HashMap<>();
hashMap2.put("notificationId", mNotificationId);     
hashMap2.put("like", true);
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(postid).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(hashMap2);
}
```

**delete func:**

```
 private void deleteNotification(String userid, final String postid)) {
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid()).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());

 reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
          String notificationId = dataSnapshot.child("notificationId").getValue(String.class);

          FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications")
          .child(userid).child(notificationId).removeValue();
          reference.removeValue();
      }
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

 }
 });
 }
```

Comment: Hey Kasim, so I've been trying it all sorts of ways, and haven't been able to get it so that the notification is added / created to the database and if I unlike the comment, or delete a comment, or like or unlike a post it is removed. And I updated the code to reflect your suggestion, but now for example when I like a post by clicking on the ```ImageView``` the notification isn't even being added. It shows the notification node in red then just disappears. I'm going to upload an image of how I have my JSON

Comment: It should work. I just prevented you from deleting all notifications. Check "Notification notification" for debug mode. Is it correct?

Comment: I just tried it in the debugger mode and I am getting in the key: ```userId```, and for value: ```notificationId```. But like I said when  I like it the first time the notifications appear, and then if I unlike them, they all get erased. Also, after the first time that I unlike the post it doesn't add anymore notifications to the database they just show up red for a second and then just get deleted.

Comment: So all notification ids equal your current id. We should change methods as i said that.

Comment: No no, they're all different. Everytime that I add a new notification a new ID is created ```String notificationId = reference.push().getKey();```, but for some reason when I unlike all of the notifications are being removed. But all notifications have a unique ID. I tried another method that I wrote before this one to try to remove notifications. I will post it in a moment, but it had the problem of only removing the last notification in the list, and not the one I wanted to remove.

Comment: Just uploaded it. For this method I created a global variable ```mNotificationId``` and tried to use it to remove the notification, but as I said it only removed the last one in the list and didn't remove the other ones. I don't know if there is some way to assign it a position or something, or maybe you know an easier way?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to remove all notifications? or one notification?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212688/discussion-between-kasim-ozdemir-and-jmb).

Comment: Only one. If I like a comment and then unlike it only *THAT* must be removed. If I like a post and then unlike it only *THAT* notification must be removed. Not all of them. Only that specific notification with its specific **notificationId**. All the other ones should be untouched